# Splash screen with PersistGate

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I have below code base

**Navigator.js**
    export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        // screendesign: screendesign,
        SplashScreen: SplashScreen,
        App: drNav,
        AuthStack: AuthStack
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'SplashScreen',
      }
    ));

```
import SplashScreen from './screens/SplashScreen'
<Provider store={store}>
<PersistGate loading={<SplashScreen/>} persistor={persistor}>
<View style={styles.container}>
<Navigator />
</View>
</PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

**splashScreen.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
    }
    else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("AuthStack");
    }
  }
```

I am getting below error

[image]

> Before implementing redux, I have used this page as entry screen for
>   my app, showing as splash screen and behind checking if user is
>   authenticated or not, if it is authenticated redirecting to login page
>   else dashboard. It was working fine, but now I have used redux, then
>   the scenario is working similarly only diff this screen is not visible
>   since redux persis load data from storage

Please help I am new in react native unable to understand this error

Thanks

Comment: Which is line 112 in your project?

Comment: Provider is line 112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation prop is available to all components defined **inside** the navigator.
The SplashScreen component is not part of your Navigator so it doesn't have access to the navigation prop.
But I don't think you need it there.

Your SplashScreen component is a dump component that will be shown to the user for as long as the PersistGate needs to load the stored data to your redux store.
So when the loading of the data is completed you will see the rest of the components as they are defined inside the PersistGate. So I don't see why you would need to use the navigation from this loading component.

In case you do really need to access the navigation prop from the SplashScreen you can follow this guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Comment: Before implementing redux, I have used this page as entry screen for my app, showing as splash screen and behind checking if user is authenticated or not, if it is authenticated redirecting to login page else dashboard. It was working fine, but now I have used redux, then the scenario is working similarly only diff this screen is not visible since redux persis load data from storage

Comment: I see. Right now, when the SplashScreen is used from the PersistGate it doesn't have access to the navigation prop. But it will have access when the Navigator is loaded. So maybe you can check inside componentDidMount  if the navigation prop exists before using it. This way the first time it is used by PersistGate it won't do anything, but once the loading is finished the SplashScreen will be loaded again, this time by the navigator and it will do what you want it to do. Also it might worth changing your auth flow a bit using this guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: I have done similar way as redirected in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: I have changed code to if (this.state.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
      }
      else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("AuthStack");
      }
    }

Comment: and it is now showing but its taking sometime to show, any idea how to make it appear as soon as app loads

Comment: We had the same issue in our app. The problem is that until react native loads you see a white screen and it feels a bit laggy. We solved this by using this package https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen. It's a native splash screen which you can show and hide whenever you want. I suggest you use this

Comment: I successfully added this package. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code unable to find **navigation** in **SplashScreen component**.

1) Try to console that in SplashScreen component's render method.
2) Also check for redux configuration, there may be case that issue is with your redux configuration because of that your component unable to access navigation props.

Comment: I have set splash screen as default navigation